# How do I derive $n!$ from this series?

Tags: factorial

I am reading a book where the following reduction is performed, but it's not explained exactly what is going on. I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but I simply don't get how we are deriving the second line from the first line. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: what is S? you need to state the whole problem

Comment: Are you sure about that statement (it seems false) ? Where is it from ? Maybe give a bit more context.

Comment: It's from Artificial Intelligence, a Modern Approach, 3rd ed. q. 3.5. The S is the state space. I will post a screencap.

Comment: This follows by grouping like terms. Then use $(n-k) \le (n-k-l)$ (for appropriate $k,l$, of course).

Comment: now wait...this is completely not what you wanted in the first place, $S^3\ge n!$ and not $S^3=n!$

Comment: This seems to be an evolving question...

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the incomplete first version, but I hope the screengrab makes it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok the reasoning goes as follows, whatever $S^3$ is, we know that
$$
S^3\ge n*n*n*(n-3)*(n-3)*(n-3)\dots
$$
but we also know that $n>(n-1),n>(n-2)$ and $(n-3)>(n-4),(n-3)>(n-5)$ and therefore we just plug in and get the following inequality
$$
S^3\ge n*n*n*(n-3)*(n-3)*(n-3)\dots \ge n*(n-1)(n-2)*(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)\dots=n!
$$
and thats it.

bests

Comment: Ah, of course. I need to work on my inequalities... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the first line we have n*n*n which has been replace by n*(n-1)*(n-2)
This is valid because we are saying that that S^3 is greater or equal to the first line and since n*n*n > n*(n-1)*(n-2) for all n, it is a valid substitution.

The next 3 terms are (n-3)*(n-3)*(n-3) which is then replaced by (n-3)*(n-4)*(n-5).  This is valid because (n-3)*(n-3)*(n-3)>(n-3)*(n-4)*(n-5) for all n.

The factors continue repeating 3 numbers and being replaced by 3 consecutive decreasing numbers.  The new group of numbers is always less than the 3 numbers it replaced so the new group of numbers is always a valid substitution.

The advantage of these substitutions is that you can combine the numbers to equal n!

Answer (score 0):

It is true that
$$
S \ge \prod_{k=0}^K (n - 3 k)
$$
and so
\begin{align}
S^3 
& \ge \prod_{k=0}^K (n - 3 k) \cdot (n - 3 k)  \cdot (n - 3k) \\ 
& \ge \prod_{k=0}^K (n - 3 k) \cdot (n - 3 k - 1) \cdot (n - 3k -2) = n!
\end{align}
if $n - 3K - 2 = 1$ or $K=n/3-1$.

Comment: ah, ok, that looks nicer, although it is $S^3\ge\dots$

Comment: don't want to be a nitpicker, but the first $=$ needs to be a $\ge$

Comment: Details, details, .. :-)